# How to build a pip python package from the github repository with nix

Tags: python, nix

I gave the right repo and version
but according to the error, the source can't be download

```
{
  description = "virtual environment with python and streamlit";
  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        python=pkgs.python311;

    xTuring = pkgs.python3Packages.buildPythonPackage rec {
      name = "xTuring";
      version = "0.16";

      src = pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
         owner = "stochasticai";
            repo = "${name}";
            rev = "${version}";
            #sha256 = "1ibrwal80z27c2mh9hx85idmzilx6cpcmgc15z3lyz57bz0krigb";
      };

    };

        
        f = ps: with ps;[
          ipython
          matplotlib
          pandas

        ];        
        pip_python_packages= python.withPackages(f);

        myDevTools = [
          pip_python_packages
          pkgs.streamlit
          xTuring
        ];
      in rec {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = myDevTools;
        };
      });
}
```

> warning: found empty hash, assuming
> 'sha256-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=' error: builder
> for '/nix/store/lnpnyfdq132wl3g82h66v8qldg2mnbw0-source.drv' failed
> with exit code 1;
> last 8 log lines:
> >
> > trying https://github.com/stochasticai/xTuring/archive/0.16.tar.gz
> >   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
> >                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
> >   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
> >   0    14    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
> > curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
> > error: cannot download source from any mirror
> For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/lnpnyfdq132wl3g82h66v8qldg2mnbw0-source.drv'. error: 1
> dependencies of derivation
> '/nix/store/p90maxb3jvyry1m57zypil2ybq1ssbvx-python3.10-xTuring.drv'
> failed to build error: 1 dependencies of derivation
> '/nix/store/3ad8nfn68zljv1rnrzh2665s7yz7fg0p-nix-shell-env.drv' failed
> to build

According to the error message, nix search to download  https://github.com/stochasticai/xTuring/archive/0.16.tar.gz .

Why?

Answer (score 0):

That was a silly problem:

"v0.1.6" instead of 0.16